# How to get response from web API call

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have an API that I want to call and get the response back. Then I want to assign that response to a variable.

I have an API like:

```
http://example.org/Webservicesms_get_userbalance.aspx?user=xxxx&passwd=xxxx
```

When I run this URL in a browser, it prints an SMS balance. I want this SMS balance as a response and then assign it to a variable in my page.

Comment: ajax call might get your job done...

Comment: @Yves M   can you please describe ??

Comment: What have you tried, and which part is giving you problems?  Which search terms have you used that have come up empty, for example?  Please respond by editing the question to add this info...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your service is an .aspx page which just returns text (the sms balance) and no html?
If so you can 'scrape it'

```
string urlData = String.Empty;
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
urlData = wc.DownloadString("http://domainname/Webservicesms_get_userbalance.aspx?user=xxxx&passwd=xxxx");
```

Answer (score 9):

You may also use [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) class.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://domainname/Webservicesms_get_userbalance.aspx?user=xxxx&passwd=xxxx");

// Get the response.
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Cleanup the streams and the response.
reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

Of course, you can change `Console.WriteLine` to whatever you want to do with response.

Comment: +1; This is probably the more common example I've seen.  But why is it superior to the answer Neil gave?  Will it work with older code?  Are there fewer assemblies you need to include to get this to work?

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham Don't think my answer is superior to Neil's. One thing I can say that WebClient needs STA thread to run in it. And WebRequest is supported in .NET 4, 3.5, 3.0, 2.0, 1.1, 1.0, so it should work.

Comment: This feels faster than using DownloadString.